# MDX : calculated measure gives different result with "where" and "from select"

Tags: mdx, iccube

I have a problem with 2 MDX statements, the first one gives the correct result, but the second one is different as expected.

As the MDX is build dynamically I'd rather prefer to use the second one.

```
create calculated member [Sejours Ambulatoire] as sum([Ambu].[Ambu].[Ambu].[Ambulatoire], NbSejours)
create calculated member [Taux Ambulatoire] as IIF( [Ambu].[Ambu].current is [Ambu].[Ambu].[Non Ambulatoire], 0, divN([Sejours Ambulatoire], [Measures].[NbSejours] , 0)   ), format_string='percent'
```

1st code :

```
select [Measures].[Taux Ambulatoire] on 0
from [Cube]
where  {[Ambu].[Ambu].[Non Ambulatoire]} * {[Etablissement].[Lieu établissement].[All-M].&[CHU de Brest]} * { [Periode].[Periode].[All-M].&[2014] }
```

-- Result 0,00% Correct

2nd Code :

```
SELECT
 { [Measures].[Taux Ambulatoire] }  ON 0
 FROM ( SELECT
{ [Periode].[Periode].[All-M].&[2014] } ON 0,
{ [Etablissement].[Lieu établissement].[All-M].&[CHU de Brest] } ON 1,
{ [Ambu].[Ambu].[Non Ambulatoire] } ON 2
     FROM [Cube])
```

-- Result 120,86%  INCORRECT

Can someone explain the difference ?

Comment: I'll answer this week-end, it's one of the complexities of MDX, overwritten hierarchies. Takes some time to get used, where you define your tuples, change the way they are calculated. You could also try the where option , that is closer to the 1st version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the iSin(GetFilterInfo()) suggestion.

```
with member [Taux Ambulatoire Test] as iif(isIn( GetFilterInfo([Ambu].[Ambu]) , [Ambu].[Ambu].[Non Ambulatoire] ), 0, divN([Sejours Ambulatoire], [Measures].[NbSejours] , 0)   ), format_string='percent'
SELECT
 { [Measures].[Taux Ambulatoire Test] }  ON 0
, [Ambu].[Ambu] on 1
 FROM ( SELECT
{ [Periode].[Periode].[All-M].&[2014] } ON 0,
{ [Etablissement].[Lieu établissement].[All-M].&[CHU de Brest] } ON 1
--,{ [Ambu].[Ambu].[Non Ambulatoire] } ON 2
     FROM [Cube])
```

which works better but not in the case where I want to get all the [Ambu].[Ambu] on rows, I still get 120,86% for NonAmbulatoire...

The only solution I found is to create a measure for the SejoursNonAmbulatoire.  Then the [Taux Ambulatoire] is checking if the whole selection is NonAmbulatoire...

```
create calculated member [Sejours Ambulatoire] as sum([Ambu].[Ambu].[Ambu].[Ambulatoire], NbSejours)
create calculated member [Sejours NONAmbulatoire] as sum([Ambu].[Ambu].[Ambu].[Non Ambulatoire], NbSejours)
create calculated member [Taux Ambulatoire] as IIF( [Sejours NONAmbulatoire] = [Measures].[NbSejours], 0, divN([Sejours Ambulatoire], [Measures].[NbSejours] , 0)   ), format_string='percent'
```

Answer (score 1):

Don'g forget that in icCube you've an MDX debugger that will help you understand how the different parts of MDX statements are solved.

The question is how this expression is solved :

```
[Ambu].[Ambu].current
```

Current is **not** taking the values from the subselect filter definition. It takes values from the other sources: where clause, axis, and tuples defined in a calculated member.

Two possible solutions

1) Put the filter in a where clause instead of in a filter, so *current* is going to return the tuple as defined in the where clause.

2) To get IIF working you can use [GetFilterInfo](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/GetFilterInfo.php) function that returns the content of the subselect and the where clause

```
isIn( GetFilterInfo([Ambu].[Ambu]) , [Ambu].[Ambu].[Non Ambulatoire] )
```

Nonetheless I'd check my statement carefully.